# QTableWidget cellClicked signal not working

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I have a QTableWidget in my application and I have connected the cellClicked(int,int) signal to a slot. But this code in the slot doesn't get called at all when a cell is clicked. Please let me know how this can be resolved. This is my code:

```
connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(x,y)), this, SLOT(myCellClicked(x,y)));
```

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros only handle type names, not variable names, so it should be:

```
connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int,int)), this, SLOT(myCellClicked(int,int)));
```

Comment: If I have a button in that cell, it looks like this signal is not being raised. How do I make sure this signal is also raised?

Comment: @RakeshK I don't think that signal will be emitted if you have a real button in the cell. It would be better to paint a fake button with a delegate (see [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2767178/894321) ).